# Turing Machine for $ = \{^n ^ c^{2^{nm}} : n,m\ge 1 \}$

Tags: turing-machines

**This question requires high level description of Turing machine.**

I found that we are able to solve **a^n b^m c^nm** by :

Step 1 :  crossing out one a

Step 2 :  continue to cross out one b followed by one c once  until b are all crossed out.

Step 3 : we restore all the b's and continue looping until all a's are crossed out.

If there is no c left, we accept. Else, reject.

I was thinking if this would be related to the question where c has a power of ( 2 ^nm )?